# Vagrant-Azure: Guest machine can't connect to host machine (Unable to copy SMB files)

Tags: azure, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin

I've been working on Vagrant only locally until now and now I want to create VM with Azure as the provider, but unfortunately I've got the error that can be seen on the image accesible through the link. I understand what it says but I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tplg.png)

I am also appending my Vagrantfile:

```
require 'vagrant-azure'
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'azure'
  config.vm.box_url = 'https://github.com/azure/vagrant-azure/raw/master/dummy.box'

  config.vm.network "private_network", guest: 80, host: 80

  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/id_rsa'

  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', :disabled => true

  config.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|
    azure.tenant_id = ****
    azure.client_id = ****
    azure.client_secret = ****
    azure.subscription_id = ****

    azure.tcp_endpoints = '80'

    azure.vm_name = 'grafmuvivm'
    azure.vm_size = 'Standard_B1s'
    azure.vm_image_urn = 'Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-LTS:latest'
    azure.resource_group_name = 'grafmuvirg'
    azure.location = 'westeurope'
    virtual_network_name = 'grafmuvivm-vagrantPublicIP'
  end

  # Declare where chef repository path
  chef_repo_path = "./chef"

  # Provisioning Chef-Zero
  config.vm.provision :chef_zero do |chef|
    # Added necessary chef attributes
    chef.cookbooks_path = 'chef/cookbooks'
    chef.nodes_path = 'chef/cookbooks'

    #### Adding recipes ####
    chef.add_recipe "api::ssh_user"
    chef.add_recipe "api::grafmuvi"

    # Running recipes
    chef.run_list = [
      'recipe[api::ssh_user]',
      'recipe[api::grafmuvi]'
    ]
    # Accept chef license
    chef.arguments = "--chef-license accept"
  end
end
```

If I run 'vagrant up --debug' it can be seen that guest machine cannot ping any of the host machine IPs.

Could someone please tell me how to properly setup networking on Vagrant? I've checked the GitHub issues related to this topic but I didn't find anything useful...

EDIT:

[image: Running 'vagrant provision']

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Vagrant but not with Vagrant-azure. But, can you change configuration in the following way and show the output:

```
        azure.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In this case IP is my host IP I assume?

Comment: no, this is the node ip you will try to ping after virtual box creation

Comment: It says that azure.vm doesn't exist.

Comment: `vagrant status` would show all available running vms. Can you check if the vm is up and running? If it is, try `vagrant provision` and show the logs.

Comment: I've tried that before, VM is running and I can even make ssh connection with it, but I can't provision it cause SMB files are not copied... I'll add logs in edit.